Cannot Find Symbol error - Java - Encapsulation
I have this folder structure
Day12
|  Account.java
|  AccountMain.java
Account.java Contains
package Day12;

public class Account {
    int id;
    String name;
    double balance;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }
    
    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    
    
}

And my AccountMain.java
package Day12;

public class AccountMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account acc1 = new Account();

        acc1.setId(1);
        acc1.setName("John");
        acc1.setBalance(1000.0);

        System.out.println("Account ID: " + acc1.getId());
        System.out.println("Account Name: " + acc1.getName());
        System.out.println("Account Balance: " + acc1.getBalance());
    }
}

Everytime I run the javac AccountMain.java I get this error.

AccountMain.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
Account acc1 = new Account();
^   symbol:   class Account   location: class AccountMain AccountMain.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
Account acc1 = new Account();
^   symbol:   class Account   location: class AccountMain 2 errors

I get confused to as I dont know ehy it says It cannot Find symbol even tho I have them in the same Package and my aitocomplete was able to detect the Account Class.

You need to run javac in the directory which is the root of your packages, i.e. above Day12.

Try compiling both classes together.

@Abra, I'm using VS code and Java 17.

Does this answer your question? Cannot find class in same package

You can try the following steps

try a clean build

Check for the order of compilation or you can manually compile in the order



javac Day12/Account.java

javac Day12/AccountMain.java



This does work for me, thank you. But I really find it weird as when I try it in IntelliJ it doesn't run into that error but when I'm doing it in VS code. I encounter this.
